# Generate route url from subdomain to the main domain

Tags: laravel, routes, wildcard-subdomain

I have a multi-tenant app. So let's say I have test.app.com and app.com. I can successfully navigate from app.com to test.app.com but I am unable to the opposite.

I tried wrapping the routes of my app.com inside a Route::domain() but that only gives me a 404 error instead of actually redirecting it to the url

EDIT: Just to make sure, I want to redirect using a relative path (with the `route()` method).

Comment: You mean redirecting it relatively, because if you use absolute URL this won't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I will edit it. But yeah, using the route() method

Comment: Have you tried using [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)? Those could solve the issue you're having.

Comment: Yeah, I am using named routes and it doesn't help sadly :(